# Request timed out on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, httpexception

I am creating a payroll application and i have to do processing of over 500 employees. When I run the application on my local machine, it would run the application and produce correct information. It would take close to 3-4 mins to complete the processing of data. When i deploy my application to `IIS` and try to run it, i would get the following error below:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Request timed out.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]
```

I tried changing the `connection time out (seconds) to 600` in the advance setting for `IIS` for that particular Site but that didnt work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change web.config parameter `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="90"/>`
90 - is default value in seconds
you need to set greater value

Comment: You can do that but... 3-4 minutes sounds like a long running job in a web world. May be start job on a separate thread and post updates from that thread to DB. direct user to a page which can periodically check the status of that job. Or use SignalR.